# Azure:Use different blobs in staging and production

Tags: wcf, azure, lucene.net

I'm developing a WCF clous service in windows Azure, and i use lucene indexing. I would like to implement new feutures in my service, and it will use a different different blob file, becouse the new feuture requires a different index structure.
Is there any way to do it easyly?

For example: the production will use blob called: "index", and the staging will use a blob called "index_staging". 
I cant modify the current blob, because the current service will not able to work on the new index.

Thank for help.

T

Comment: By "staging" do you mean Azure's definition of "Production" vs "Staging"? Or when you say "staging", do you mean your own separate test environment?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use different storage accounts. Use a storage account for production and one for your testing environment. Example:

- myapp.blob.core.windows.net
- myapp-test.blob.core.windows.net

When you deploy to production you'll go to the first one, when you develop locally or you deploy to test environment go to the second storage account.